# Waterline takes to long to return the value

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

we've meet with really weird problem. Our simple queries to MongoDB takes really long time to return any document. Database is well indexed. We've made few tests and here they are:

```
File.find({sharename: '7iPJUtP2'}, function(err, shares){
      console.log(err,shares);
});
```

console.log fires after 60s.

Then we use .native() method:

```
File.native(function(err, collection){
      collection.find({sharename: '7iPJUtP2'}, {})
         .toArray(function (err, results) {
            console.log(err,results);
         });
});
```

Here console.log fires in 103ms.

The stack we use is:

- sails: 0.11.0
- sails-mongo: 0.11.5
- MongoDB: 2.0.1
- Waterline: 0.10.28

Can someone help with this issue?

**Update**

File.find({sharename: '1'}) executes in 50ms.

File.find({sharename: 'a'}) executes in 18000ms.

Documents are identical except of sharename field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem. Mongo query builder makes query to look like `.find({ sharename: /^qwerty$/i }})` instaed of 
`.find({ sharename: 'qwerty' }})`. It works great in latest MongoDB versions, but for mongo 2.0.1 it doesn't use indexes.

I had to fix this issue directly in sails-mongo package.
I have create fork, so if anyone will meet this problem you can use it.
https://github.com/rparaschak/sails-mongo.git